# error: Invalid use of incomplete type struct Subject; error: forward declaration of struct Subject

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I inheriting from a template class. When I make an entry in teacher class, I want to make an entry in subject class & vice versa.
I get an error Invalid use of incomplete type struct Subect;

```
void addSubject(Subject *s) {
            this->addReference(s);
            s->addReference(this); when I comment this line the it compiles without errors, but I cannot insert into Subject 

        }
```

My entire code is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class Subject;


template <class T>
class abstractReference {


    vector<T*> list;
    public:
    string code;
        void addReference(  T*);
        void delReference(  T*);
        bool hasReference(  T*);
        T * getReference(int );
};

template <class T>
void abstractReference<T>::addReference(T* ref) {
    list.push_back(ref);
    //ref->addReference(this);
}

template <class T>
void abstractReference<T>::delReference(T* ref) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if (list[i]== ref) list.erase(i);
    }

}

template <class T>
bool abstractReference<T>::hasReference( T* ref) {
  if (list.size() == 0) return false;
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
      if (list[i] == ref) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

template <class T>
T* abstractReference<T>::getReference(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > list.size()) return NULL;
    return list[i];
}

class Teacher : public abstractReference<Subject> {

    string fname;
    string lname;
    float  sal;
public:
    Teacher(string c, string fn, string ln, float s): fname(fn), lname(ln), sal(s) {
    }
    Teacher() {sal =0; fname=""; lname="";}
    void setInfo(string c, string fn, string ln, float s=0.00) {
        code=c;
        fname = fn;
        lname = ln;
        sal = s;
    }

    string getName() {
        return fname + " " + lname;
    }

    float getSal() {
        return sal;
    }

    void addSubject(Subject *s) {
        this->addReference(s);
        s->addReference(this);

    }

    void delSubject(Subject *s) {

    }

};

class Subject : public abstractReference<Teacher> {
  string title;
public:
  Subject(string c=NULL, string t=NULL) {
      title = t;

  }
  string getTitle() {
      return title;
  }
};

main() {
    Teacher *t;
    t = new Teacher("J109", "Dexter", "McConnell",15000);
    Subject *s, *s1, *s2;
    s= new Subject("E001", "English");
    s1= new Subject("M001", "Maths");
    s2= new Subject("s001", "Science");

    t->addSubject(s);
    t->addSubject(s1);

    cout << "Has Reference " << t->hasReference(s2) << endl;
    cout << "Done..." << endl;
    cout << t->getReference(1)->getTitle() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler does not understand the type `Subject`, You probably forward declared it or forgot to include the header file which defines it.
The result is that for the compiler `Subject` is an **Incomplete type** and it cannot performa any operation by which it needs to know the layout of `Subject`, Calling its member function is one such instance.

Solution is:

You should include the header file which defines `Subject` in the source cpp file where you have the definition for:

```
void addSubject(Subject *s)
```

In case you don't have multiple files, Make sure class `Subject` is defined *before* You have the definition of the function `addSubject()`.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler tries to compile the class `Teacher` the class `Subject` hasn't been *defined* yet, only *declared*. So the compiler doesn't know what methods exist in `Subject` yet.

My suggestion is that you move the body of the function to *below* the definition of `Subject`.

Something like this:

```
class Teacher : public abstractReference<Subject> {
    // ...

    void addSubject(Subject *s);

    // ...
};

class Subject : public abstractReference<Teacher> {
    // ...
};

void Teacher::addSubject(Subject *s) {
    // ...
}
```